# Altium: Create library part from a schematic symbol

Tags: schematics, library, altium

I have a schematic but not its associated library. All symbols in the schematic have proper details such as description, manufacturer, part #, etc... Is there a way to extract all this information and create a library using the symbol found in the schematic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. It's surprisingly simple.

Design -> Make schematic library.

Comment: That seems to dump all my symbols into the same new library. Even the symbols that were already in other libraries. Do I need to go into the new library and one by one clean out the redundant components?

Comment: @peterdudley - Yes, probably.